# I want to have several equations be aligned using “alignat” in a subequations environment

Tags: alignat

I want to have several equations be aligned using `alignat`.

When I use `alignat` the result is fine (see code section 1), irrespective of the length of the equation. However, when I use `alignat` in a `subequations` environment the result isn’t correct and it seems to depend on the length of the equation (see code section 2).

How can this problem be solved? Thanks for your support in advance.

Section 1: code without using `subequations`:

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &a     &&=b ~,\label{1a}\\[1ex]
 &alpha &&=beta~,\label{1b} \\[1ex]
 &c     &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) - 
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923}{kN/m^2} \label{1c} \\[1ex]
 &cc    &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) - 
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923.08}{kN/m^2} \label{1d} 
\end{alignat}%
```

Section 2: code with `subequations`:

```
{\allowdisplaybreaks [4]
\begin{subequations}\label{1}
%\noeqref{1a,1b,1c,1d}
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &a     &&=b ~,\label{1a}\\[1ex]
 &alpha &&=beta~,\label{1b} \\[1ex]
 &c     &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) - 
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923}{kN/m^2} \label{1c} \\[1ex]
 &cc    &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) - 
            2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923.08}{kN/m^2} \label{1d}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}}%
```

Comment: Apart from your alignment and symbol choice, both versions compile without problem ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaJJ7.png)). Can you describe what the problem is?